# How to modify the class "Array" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm new about ruby! I just wanna do the following:

```
module Functional
  def filter
  end
end

class Array
  include Functional
  def filter
  end
end

a = [1, -2, 3, 7, 8]
puts a.filter{|x| x>0}.inspect      # ==>Prints out positive numbers
```

How could I modify the method "filter" in Array?
Could anybody help me? Thank you

Comment: That works for me. Prints out nil as expected

Comment: Try to create a reproduction test-case on http://ideone.com or similar (against a specific Ruby version, ideone is currently Ruby 1.9.3) so the behavior can be verified - for instance, when [I try, I get `nil` as output](http://ideone.com/KRvXTR) . Counterexample? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
class Array
  alias filter :select
end

a = [1, -2, 3, 7, 8]
a.filter{|x| x > 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
module Functional
  def filter
    return self.select{ |i| i > 0 }
  end
end

class Array
  include Functional
end

a = [1, -2, 3, 7, 8]
puts a.filter{|x| x>0}.inspect      
#=>[1, 3, 7, 8]
```

Although I think you can save yourself the trouble by just using `select` -- there's no need to reimplement it.

Comment: Oh, the comment was what OP wanted to do, not what OP was seeing and wondering why it wasn't being re-defined.